# Uploadify Oncomplete

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, uploadify

In Uploadify i need to return the file name which was uploaded by uplod.php.How can get it back in onComplete section?

Comment: 'onComplete': function(event,ID,fileObj,response,data) {
  alert('data');
  
  }   I have use in this manner but its not firing onComplete and not showing alert() for me.

Comment: function(event, ID, fileObj, response, data) {

      alert('There are ' + fileObj.name + ' file');

    }    - - read the manual

Answer (score 3):

onComplete': function(event, ID, fileObj, response, data) {

alert('You have uploaded ' + fileObj.name + ' to ' + fileObj.filePath + '.');

}

Answer (score 0):

Look in the Uploadify doc for:

```
onComplete': function(event, ID, fileObj, response, data) {}
```

Sure you can retrieve the file name in data ;)

EDIT : `fileDataName` returns you what you need apparently.

In my case, I send the needed info, and set the name in upload.php when I move and rename the file.

Answer (score 0):

fileDataName return string name

read documentation: http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/

also in function there is `[name] - The name of the uploaded file`

http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/events/oncomplete-2/

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
'onUploadComplete': function(file) {
     alert(file.name);
}
```

And Its working.